# How to print structures in C programming, anything similar to the toString() method of Java in c?

Tags: java, c, struct

I'm working on a C project. My project is to create a binary tree, this is my struct:

```
struct Node
{
  char * word;
  int count;
  struct Node* left;
  struct Node* right;
};
```

My question is how to print the struct, do I use `printf()` for each one of the field or there is a way to create a `toString()` method like in Java.
What do you guys recommend? What's the easiest way?

**I just realized I can create a method call `print()` and use `printf` and cast  all the fields. Sorry but if you know a better way please let me know.**

Comment: No there is no way like toString(), you have to make your own method

Comment: Is this for `c++` or for `c`?

Comment: How do you think it's done in Java?  It doesn't happen automatically -- each `toString` method must be coded separately.

Comment: for c , do i really need to cast every time i use prinf(,(cast)),

Comment: @TejasPatel No, that was to OP. In `C++` there is `.c_str()` which as you probably know is almost, but not entirely, similar in some respects.

Comment: @user3597577: it's `printf`, not `prinf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No real magic:

```
struct Node node = {"Adam", 1, NULL, NULL};
struct Node *nodePtr = &node;

printf("word[%s] count[%d] left[%p] right[%p]\n",
  node.word, node.count, node.left, node.right);

printf("word[%s] count[%d] left[%p] right[%p]\n",
  nodePtr->word, nodePtr->count, nodePtr->left, nodePtr->right);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ I would write a `tostring()` method for each node and call them recursively. But in c, try this.

```
struct Node node1 = {"Adam", 1, NULL, NULL};
struct Node node2 = {"Bert", 2, &node1, NULL};

void printit(Node* node) {
  printf("word[%s] count[%d] left[%p] right[%p]\n",
    node->word, node->count, node->left, nodePtr->right);
  if (node->left) printit(node->left);
  if (node->right) printit(node->right);
}

printit(&node2);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. C is not object-oriented, and there's no general-purpose facility for turning C data into strings. You'll have to write your own function to either turn your struct into a string or print it out directly.